# Artifactory remote repository not up-to-date

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse, artifactory

I have 2 artifactory servers.  Let say `A` and `B`.

One of them, `A`, has a remote repository pointing to the other, `B`.

My eclipse maven plugin (m2e) is configured to use `B`.

Let say I have on `A` an achetype `myArchetype-1.0.jar`.

The first time I use New maven project, the `archetype-catalog.xml` is downloaded on `B` and I can see the version `1.0` of `myArchetype`.  Ok, it's good.

Now I publish the `2.0` version on `A`.  The `archetype-catalog.xml` is also updated.

Back to eclipse, new maven project, the `myArchetype` is still with version `1.0`.  Nothing is updated on `B`.

What can I do to have the remote repository up-to-date ?

Comment: Why do you have two artifactory servers? Does not make sense.

Comment: I have one in my professional network, behind a proxy with credentials and one outside.  Unfortunately, m2e plug in is not able to use proxy nor dos command line. And my inside server is not accessible from outside.  So the only solution I found is to deploy my archetypes on the outside server (some developpers are outside) et add a remote repository on the inside one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifactory does not support Maven Archetypes. That means that it is not aware of the fact that `archetype-catalog.xml` is expirable and should be checked for changes.

If your Artifactory is Pro, you can implement the re-check via user plugin.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I don't have the pro version. An idea of another solution ?

Comment: Yes, you need to trigger REST API to delete the `archetype-catalog.xml` on `B` when you publish new artifact on `A`. Probably with some `maven-rest-plugin` or something.

Comment: Thanks.  I will see how I can do that.  But at first sight, the problem is that artifacts are always published on A and I don't have any access on B from outside.  If I found something, I will publish a response.

Comment: I see. What might work is a script that nukes the file in `B` once in a while.